# jumpy scrolling with mouse wheel on chorme (Windows)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm having an issue with my website, basically when scrolling with mouse wheel on chrome on Windows, the page behave in a strange way and keeps doing strange jumps.
I've trying add the css rule

```
html {
  scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```

but in that way another issue appeard when scrolling down, it does 3 steps down and 1 slow step up.
I've checked but I'm not even using particular javascript (in some pages not at all). I've also tried to change mouse settings on windows but it didn't solve the problem (also I've noticed the issue on different windows laptops but no issue with other browsers and on mac)

Do you have any idea what can cause this? Thank you

EDIT 2020/12/27

I found the problem was a script put in the head of the page by some developer who had previously worked on the website and that was supposed to make the scroll smoother

Comment: Would you be able to share the website in question? Maybe a slow event listener on scroll?

Comment: Have you checked it with another mouse?

Comment: @Kosh yes, I've tried both different mouse and different computers, it seems like it's a chrome on windows issue

Comment: @baband, it would be great if you added a [mcve] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scroll-behaviour` rather than `scrolling-behaviour`. Docs for [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior). It's probably not possible to advise much more without a link to the website.

```
html {
  scroll-behaviour: smooth;
}
```

This property only really deals with scrolling triggered via a browser API though, not with the mousewheel.

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake, I meant "scroll-behaviour"